# Compile a java file that depends on a jar file

Tags: java, command-line, junit, compilation

I have the following files, both has the same package definition:

```
awesome.java
awesomeTest.java
```

the package (and directories) for these files is :
 `package awe.some`

I try to compile them in **command line**
However they don't seem to compile, since `awesomeTest.java` use `import junit.framework.*;`

How do I compile this properly in command line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as for running java classes: the jar must be in the classpath for the compiler to be able to load the classes it contains:

```
javac -cp /path/of/junit-4.1.jar awe/some/awesomeTest.java
```

Note that classes from junit.framework are obsolete in JUnit4. You should not use them anymore for new tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
javac -cp junit-4.1.jar;. awe/some/*.java
```